# how to package backing bean controller manager facade business logic

Tags: jsf, architecture

I have looked at several JavaEE 6 login tutorials using servlet 3.0 and JSFtechnology.  Often it shows a request scoped credentials bean and a user manager session bean.  Most do not provide packaging info or for simplicity sake create everything in one package.  I have been struggling with the packaging between the web tier and the business logic.  I do not know if backing bean, controller, manager, and facade are all talking about the same thing or not.  A short answer could tell me how to package a user manager session bean and the credentials bean, but a more appreciated answer would help me navigate the web tier and the business logic.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For packaging I like to break first by functionality (like core, gui) and then by business unit level.

for e.g

```
com.comp.db.beans // place your database beans here (if using any orm )

com.comp.web.ui.controller // place your controller, managedbeans here, this can be again broken into functionality wise like login, processing e.t.c.
com.comp.web.ui.beans //you place your vo here
```

In order to start packaging you have to first write down the different functionality of your system.

Then break them into business unit wise

Then break those into more finer level, to distinguish if functionality is going to be very specific to ui, or does it belong to core.

Comment: "//you place your vo here".  What is "vo"

Comment: VO = Value Object or call it dataobject (which you share with your UI)

Comment: Can you give me a reference to an article, tutorial or book which would walk me thru doing it this way; especially the web.ui. Thanks for your reply.